# How to access NSUserDefaults of a different user when being root?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults, cfpreferences

Provided my app has the access permissions (such as when running as `root`), how can it access the preferences of a particular user?

For example, let's assume a user relaunches, from a normal (Admin) account, my regular app (bundle) as root, e.g. with sudo, like this:

```
sudo /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

or even from an app with

```
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()
```

If my app now calls `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults`, it will access the prefs stored inside the root user's home directory.

I like to make it possible for this app of mine to access the logged-in user's prefs instead.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there must be a way because I can do the same with the `defaults` command: I can specify a path to a plist file, like this:

```
sudo -s
defaults read /Users/username/Library/Preferences/some.plist.name
```

This will read the prefs of that user, even though `whoami` returns `root`.

So, the solution is to do this:

```
NSString *domain = @"/Users/username/Library/Preferences/some.plist.name";
NSUserDefaults myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:domain];
```

And then use `myDefaults` all over my app.

**Update**

Actually, this does *not* work. I tought at first it would, but it seems that this will simply access the root user's preferences.

So, while there must be a way to accomplish this (if the defaults command can do it, then we should as well), but it's not through NSUserDefaults. Maybe it works with the `CFPreferences` API. Will have to keep investigating.